# How can i increase kivy On screen keyboard height

Tags: kivy

I am developing the application with kivy on raspberry pi. but I got stuck at some point.

How can i increase kivy "Vkeyboard" height ?

I could not find any documents on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

When you request a keyboard using something like:

```
self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
```

You can change its height using:

```
self._keyboard.widget.height = 500
```

Obviously, any height you want can be used.